# How to use jsr223 variables in loop controller in jmeter

Tags: testing, groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I have created a list of lists in jsr223 preprocessor and want to run a loop for size of list and print the elements in list in post processor inside the loop. But i am unable to use the count variable in loop controller.
[image]

[image]

[image]

The end result i need is in first iteration of loop [1,2,3,4,5]
second iteration [6,7,8,9,10]

at present im getting no output because loop controller is not reading count variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JSR223 PreProcessor](https://www.blazemeter.com/jsr223-preprocessor) is being executed **before** request so by the time your [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) is being kicked off your `count` variable is not initialized yet.

**Convert JSR223 PreProcessor into a [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)** and your code should start working as expected.

If you don't want JSR223 Sampler to appear in your test results add the next line to your script:

```
SampleResult.setIgnore()
```